# Wp_query: sort by PHP variable

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, sort, order

Here is my problem:

For my articles, I use a custom post type "exhibitions" and posts for all other news. I am displaying them in one query ['post_type' = array('exhibitions','posts')].

The **orderby parameter** for posts should be their *publish date*, for exhibitions it should be *custom meta value* (end date of the project). That way, posts would be displayed in following order:

1. Exhibition 1 (publish date: 2.1. 2013, end date: 4.4. 2013)
2. Post 1 (publish date: 13.3. 2013)
3. Exhibition 2 (publish date: 1.4. 2012, end date: 1.3. 2013)
4. Post 2 (publish date: 28.2. 2013)

### Define PHP variable from date (posts) and end-date meta value (exhibitions) and then sort by it?

I came up with an idea to define PHP variable (end-date meta value for exhibitions, publish date for posts) and sort the wp_query by that.

Am I going in the right direction or not? If so, how to incorporate the variable to wp_query? I've found some related articles/questions, but none of them helped me so far.

### Orderby filter?

Orderby filter sounds also as the way to go: [Orderby filter @Wordpress.org forums](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/sorting-by-custom-fieds-with-the-posts_orderby-filter)

Thanks!

///

Johaness's solutions is pretty much what I was aiming for. Here is my slightly modified function:

```
function save_sort_meta( $post_id ) {
$prev_val = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'sort_date', true );
/* set value only if not set yet (i.e. if this is a new post and not an update ) */
if ( 'exhibitions' === $_POST['post_type'] ) {
        $my_meta = get_post_meta( $post_id, '_my_meta', true );
    $datum_end_hidden = $my_meta['datum-end-hidden'];
    update_post_meta( $post_id, 'sort_date', $datum_end_hidden);
} else {
    /* using time() assuming "end_date" is a unix timestamp, adjust if not */
    update_post_meta( $post_id, 'sort_date', time());
}
}
add_action( 'save_post', 'save_sort_meta' );
```

And here's my query:

```
$args = array(
'showposts' => '22',
'post_type' => array('post','exhibitions'),
'post_status' => 'publish',
'meta_key' => 'sort_date',
'order' => 'DESC',
'orderby' => 'meta_value_num'
);
```

For some reason, "post" posts stay in the end of the wp_query (although when I echo custom value "sort_date", it shows correctly and is larger than exhibitions, that should stay "bellow").

Does it have some connection with my removal of checking the update of the post? I did it, because I want to change values on update as well.

### Edit: Code above works!

Okay, I found out where was the problem - it's quite embarassing. :) The "end date" meta value of "exhibition" post types was provided by jQuery UI Datepicker - which saves the date in miliseconds.

All I needed to do was to divide $datum_end_hidden by 1000. :)

Thank you VERY MUCH!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, you cannot sort a query by two different parameters without an additional iteration over the retrieved posts.

Since that ideally should be avoided, let me suggest a different approach:

How about incorporating an additional meta value "sort_date", or the like? And then, in your saving routine, save either the end date of the exhibition or the publish date as "sort_date".

Saving:

```
function save_sort_meta( $post_id ) {
    $prev_val = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'sort_date', true );
    /* set value only if not set yet (i.e. if this is a new post and not an update ) */
    if ( empty($prev_val) ) {
        if ( 'exhibitions' === $_POST['post_type'] ) {
            update_post_meta( $post_id, 'sort_date', $_POST['end_date'] );
        } else {
            /* using time() assuming "end_date" is a unix timestamp, adjust if not */
            update_post_meta( $post_id, 'sort_date', time() );
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'save_post', 'save_sort_meta' );
```

The Query:

```
$args = array(
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'post_type' = array( 'exhibitions', 'posts' ),
    'meta_key' => 'sort_date',
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num'
);
$exhibitions_and_posts = new WP_Query( $args );
```

As an aside, I'd recommend giving the post type a singular name.

Comment: Johannes, this is what I was looking for, thank you very much! Can you check my wp_query arguments in my edited question though? It seems I'm still missing something.

Comment: Well, the `showposts` parameter has long (really long) been deprecated, you should use `'posts_per_page' => 22` instead. Other than that, I see nothing wrong. Whether you handle your metadata correctly I cannot say, for I don't know your setup. It however is weird to save (unrelated) meta data as nested associative arrays. Is 'datum_end_hidden' really a key of an array saved under the '_my_meta' meta key? If so, you might want to rethink that in the first place.

Comment: Ok, I found out where was the problem. :) In case you're interested, you can check last edit of my question. THANK YOU VERY MUCH!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you mean you want to display 2 post types on the same page, both using a different sorting order.

If you are displaying exhibitions on their own archive, such as archive-exhibitions.php, you can set the query for that page to sort by the meta value you define.

```
$args = array(
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'post_type' => 'exhibition',
    'meta_key' => 'project_end_date',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value',
    'order' => 'DESC'
);

$my_own_query = new WP_Query($args);
```

Naturally, change `project_end_date` to reflect the key name of your project end date meta value. Change `orderby` to `meta_value_num` depending on how you save the variable. `meta_value` is probably fine.

For the Loop, you'll need to use:

```
<?php if ($my_own_query->have_posts()) : while ($my_own_query->have_posts()) : $my_own_query->the_post(); ?>
```

Now, loading that archive (http://example.com/exhibitions/) will ignore the regular WP_Query and use your `my_own_query` for the loop.

Comment: Hi Mark, thanks for your reply, although I did mean to have both post types on the **same query**. Because of this, Johaness's sollution is more likely what I'm looking for.

Comment: As a side comment, in Johaness's solution, you can use `add_action( 'wp_insert_post', 'save_sort_meta' );` instead of `add_action( 'save_post', 'save_sort_meta' );` if you only want to do this action once, when the post is newly created. If you want to update the meta value every time you update the post, use his `action`.

Comment: Sorry, I still don't have enough rep to comment on other posts... Shouldn't `!wp_is_post_revision( $post_id )` be added to the `save_sort_meta` function to prevent bloating wp_postmeta for every autosave WP makes?

Comment: Marc, I've just found out about mysteriously disappearing values at my query. This answer saved me BIG headache, so thanks again!